# data collection failure from spark dataframe to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

When I try to collect the data from spark dataframe to pandas data frame I am facing this issue.
teh spark jobs gets completed successfully, but facing issue only while collecting the data to pandas data frame.
I tried many parameters, but still I facing the issue

Config used to submit the spark job:

```
RUN_OPTIONS="--driver-memory 18g --executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 14g --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=10g --conf spark.maxRemoteBlockSizeFetchToMem=2g --conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=3600s --conf spark.network.timeout=3610s --conf spark.worker.timeout=3610s --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=5 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=50 --conf spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=36000 "`
```

Code:

```
SPARK_DF=DF_RESULT.union(dict_dq[keys])
DF_PD=SPARK_DF.toPandas()
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "serve-DataFrame" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:535)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonServer$$anon$1.run(PythonRDD.scala:886)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cgfiles/common/DQ_Check/main/runDQ.py", line 469, in <module>
    DF_RES_PD=DF_RESULT.toPandas()
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.1-1.cdh6.2.1.p5242.21315880/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 2142, in toPandas
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.1-1.cdh6.2.1.p5242.21315880/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 534, in collect
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.1-1.cdh6.2.1.p5242.21315880/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 144, in _load_from_socket
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.1-1.cdh6.2.1.p5242.21315880/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 178, in local_connect_and_auth
Exception: could not open socket: ["tried to connect to ('127.0.0.1', 38225), but an error occured: [Errno 111] Connection refused"]
```

Comment: What version of spark are you using? I'm facing this issue during a collect call, which is what is happening for you too, and using Spark 2.4.4